# Grafana / InfluxDB query counter data with a time range

Tags: influxdb, grafana, telegraf

I have a application which send metrics to influx DB and we use grafana to plot graph based on that data. For one of the metrics, application sends a counter type of data, basically whenever there is a event the count is incremented. is there way to query this type of data and plot in Grafana?

I tried using the DIFFERENCE function but the graph shows the correct value only during the 10 seconds period and then it's shown as zero.

what is the correct way to achieve this?

Example:

```
T1 : 10
T1+10minutes : 12
```

I want to see the graph as 2 between T2 and T1(10 minutes), in my case it shows 2 for 10 seconds and then reset to zero.

I am using the below influx/ grafana query

```
select difference(sum("Counter_Metrics")) FROM "My_Measurement" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time(10s), host fill(null)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: To be honest, I can not understand your question. What do you try to visualize? What does "a counter type of data" mean? Do you try to show the value increment rather than value itself?

Comment: Zeroes can appear on time range edges - two points needed to calculate difference. Is there a newer datapoint after "T1+10minutes"?

Comment: @WindyFields yes that's correct, since my application doesn't reset the counter, I want to show the increment rather than the actual value

Comment: @YuriLachin yes there will a newer data point after T1+10min with a new value. I want to see only the diff between any timestamps

Comment: I suspect that this might be related to group by time step. If your data has data points interval 10minutes and you group by 10seconds maost of intervals are going to be empty. Can you try to use GROUP BY time(10m)? Also do you really need sum() inside difference()? I would expect no function at all or last() ...

Answer (score 3):

If all you need is just a difference between the current and the previous counter values over the time (essentially, value increment) then just use `DIFFERENCE` function without any `SUM`:

```
SELECT * FROM api_calls
name: api_calls
time                         value
----                         -----
2018-03-02T17:22:53.5335191Z 1
2018-03-02T17:22:56.3249691Z 2
2018-03-02T17:22:59.619759Z  4
2018-03-02T17:23:01.6130663Z 6
2018-03-02T17:23:04.1959738Z 7
```

Every time your application reports you a new value of a counter (in my case I have API Calls Counter).

Calling `DIFFERENCE` will give me the counter increment per metrics report (per timestamp):

```
SELECT DIFFERENCE(value) FROM api_calls
name: api_calls
time                         difference
----                         ----------
2018-03-02T17:22:56.3249691Z 1
2018-03-02T17:22:59.619759Z  2
2018-03-02T17:23:01.6130663Z 2
2018-03-02T17:23:04.1959738Z 1
```